# import 'react' statement when run locally or on git-pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developed a small react application using codesandbox that I want to run locally on my machine's localhost, but I'm encountering a compile error due to this line of code.

```
import React, { StrictMode} from "react";
```

Where is the "react" file supposed to be located and if I modify it to work with my specific file set-up, then how do I ensure that the files are still available when I later import them to my github page?

Is this "react" file supposed to be available within my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual files would be in your node modules folder after having run "npm install" to tell your application to read the package.json and install any dependencies such as react.

Each time a user clones the app from github they can run npm install, the dependencies are downloaded and installed, and then they have the files locally as well. This makes it so that you do not have to transfer any dependency files via your repo.